# QTableWidgetItem not entering integers to table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm building an app in PyQt5 and am trying to populate a table in it from a list.

The code that I have so far will allow it to populate the list with string values, but the integer values are missed out.

The module I have the populates the table is:

```py
    def add_data(self):
        """Add data into the table"""

        table = self.tableWidget
        column_01 = ["a", 1, "c", 4, "d"]
        i = 1
        column_01_index = 0

        while i < len(column_01):
            table.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(column_01[column_01_index]))
            i += 1
            column_01_index += 1
```

Any idea how I can get the integers into this list without having to convert them into strings first?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they are the numeric types that python provides by default (not numpy) then you can use the Qt::DisplayRole role directly:

```py
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(column_01.items()):
    item = QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, v)
    table.setItem(i, 0, item)
```